# How to define a rectangular box for arbitrary contents in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I need a web page with this:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| label | [] a checkbox     |
+-------+ with a big text.  |
        +-------------------+
```

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <label>label</label>
    <div class="box">
        <input type="checkbox"> a checkbox with a big text
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.outer { clear: both; width: 400px; }
label { float: left; width: 100px; }
.box { dislay: table; /* also works with table-cell */ }
```

Notice that I'm using `display: table` to avoid this:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| label | [] a checkbox     |
+-------+                   |
| with a big text           |
+---------------------------+
```

The `box` div will not have any table rows or cells - just some flow content (a check box and some text, for now).

My question: Is it adequate to use `display: table`, or should I use `display: table-cell` even without an outer `display: table` element? Suppose in the future someone chooses to put all this inside a `table` element, or a `display: table` element? Which `display` option would be more robust?

Comment: why not just use .label { float: left; width: 300px; }? It works across all browsers. display: table does not work in ie6 or ie7

Comment: @Shadow_boi It doesn't work. The text gets under the label, as displayed in the second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left-col">
        <label>label</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <input type="checkbox"> a checkbox with a big text
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.outer { clear: both; width: 400px; }
.left-col { float: left; width: 100px; }
.right-col{ float: left; width: 300px; }
```

You may need to have a fixed height for both columns

Comment: This works, but I don't like to rely on adding two inner widths to make the outer width. If I need to change .outer from 400px to another value, I'll have to remember to change the 300px as well.

Comment: It's a rather clean and simple solution, what would you rather have changed?

Comment: Floating elements without width values are not recommended, you will find unexpected results in browsers such as IE6, I recommend using a width on any floating element.

Comment: I know. That's why all float elements in the question description have width. Notice the `box` is not a float element.

Comment: You could always set the width automatically with jquery, but layout with javascript is bad practice... sorry, but this is most likely your best solution...

Comment: just wondering, why do we need a extra div wrapped around the label? I thought once we apply float left to label, the label element would become a block element, just like the div.

Comment: You could always set the label to be float:left; display:block; it just looks cleaner with the two columns wrapper, personal preference...

Comment: So far, the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` are better solutions for me than `float: left`, due to extra simplicity and less dependency on siblings/parents. I just don't know which of those two are best, as described in the question. And I don't care about IE7.